# Installing Ubuntu 18.04.3 attempt on a NVMe SSD

Tags: boot, hard-drive, ssd, nvme

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 on a Ryzen 7 8-core system with a NVMe SSD AHCI SATA. The motherboard recognizes the on-board drive. The ISO installation CD reads an error message:

> no drive with file system available

The BusyBox command line comes up and I type `fdisk -l` and a "not found" message comes up.

Shouldn't the ISO recognize the drive and ask what file system I would like it to be formatted or is there some other BusyBox command I am missing?